# How to set dynamic route to use slug in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing

Let's say that I have a controller named

**pages**

and there is a method

**slug_on_the_fly**

`public function slug_on_the_fly($slug)`

How would my route for this look like?

E.g. for blog controller it would be easy:

```
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'pages/slug_on_the_fly/$1';
```

and then `http://localhost/blog/name-of-the-article` works nice

However, what if I want to do it like without `blog` so e.g.

`http://localhost/name-of-the-article` or `http://localhost/another-article-blablabla`

How to do it and don't break another routes e.g. `$route['friends'] = 'users';` or `$route['about-us'] = 'pages/about_us';` ?

Because if I do:
`$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/slug_on_the_fly/$1';`

It will probably ruin everything else or?

Comment: Any idea how to routes such situations?

Comment: Put the "catch-all" route last, and make sure that method uses `error_404()` if it doesn't find anything.

Comment: Can you be more specific? If I put `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/slug_on_the_fly/$1';` last everything before will be screwed

Comment: Routes are checked in order, so `(:any)` won't match unless no other route matched before it.

Comment: @FrancisAvila so it stops when it finds the first match? It isn't like the php code where when you write e.g. `$a = 5; `then `$a = 6;` and then `$a = 7;` then in the end the $a is not 5 but it's 7. The routes are behaving different?

Comment: Route matching is short-circuited. The *first* matching route wins, not the *last* matching one! Even if it weren't short-circuited, the workaround would be to put `(:any)` as the *first* route, right?

Comment: As soon as a route matches, it is processed and no other routes are retrieved. So they should be in order from most-specific to least. Your `(:any)` route would be last. **However**, this will break any existing controllers that do not require routes to function normally. So it's not a great solution.

Comment: Guys did you tried it? It works exactly different as you are saying."As soon as a route matches, it is processed and no other routes are retrieved." IT'S THE OPOSITE!!! E.g. I have first this: `$route['registration'] = 'auth/register';` and then this: `$route['registration'] = 'pages/index/somethingbla';` and guess what? somehtingbla is loaded because it is the last!!!. If I switch it auth/register is loaded. WHY ARE YOU GIVING ME FALSE INFORMATION??? I don't get it . try it yourself and then give advice.

Comment: @Derfder, you *replaced* the registration route in the array, you *did not add second `registration` route*. This is different from what we are talking about, e.g. with routes `$route['reg'] = 'auth/reg';  $route['(:any)'] = 'wild/card';`, url `/reg/this` goes to `Auth::reg()` and url `/blarg` goes to `Wild::card()`. Remember, **`$route` is not magic--it is an ordinary PHP array with regex keys**!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Urls are routed in the following order:

1. Explicit routes in `$route` (routes.php) are checked *in order*.
2. An implicit route `[folder/]controller/methodname/args...` is attempted as a fallback.

If have a small number of known explicit routes, you can just add them to `$route`:

```
$route['(my-slug|my-other-slug|my-third-slug)'] = 'pages/slug_on_the_fly/$1'
```

(Routes keys are really parsed as regular expressions with `:any` and `:num` are rewritten to `.+` and `[0-9]+`.)

If you have a large number of such routes (probably not a good idea, BTW!) you can just add a wildcard route to the **end** of `$route`:

```
$route['([^/]+)/?'] = 'pages/slug_on_the_fly/$1'
```

The regex here means "any url that has no slashes (except maybe last)". You can refine this to describe your slug format if you have any other restrictions. (A good one is `[a-z0-9-]+`.) If your controller finds the slug in the db, you're done. If it doesn't, it must serve a 404.

However, you give up the possibility of some implicit routing as Codeigniter doesn't provide any way for a controller to "give up" a route back to the router.  For example, if you have a controller named 'foo' and you want a url like `/foo` to route to `Foo::index()`, you must add an explicit route for this case because it would be caught by this route and sent to `Pages::slug_on_the_fly('foo')` instead. **In general, you should not have slugs which are also controller class names!** This is why you should have a very small number of these url-slugs, if you have any at all!

If you have *both* a large number of these explicit routes *and* you are not willing to abide by these implicit routing limitations, you can try adding them to `$route` dynamically:

1. Make a `routes_extra.php` file which `routes.php` includes at the end. Write new routes to it as part of saving a page or when you build/deploy the site.
2. Subclass `Router.php` and add a new routing layer.
3. Add a `pre_system` hook which adds the routes.

I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: Thanks, I am using HMVC with codeigniter and `$route['([^/]+)/?'] = 'pages/slug_on_the_fly/$1'` seems to be working. But I need to make more tests. For now, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You could use database driven routes.

Add the table `blog_slugs` to your MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_slugs` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `slug` varchar(192) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Replace the code in application/config/routes.php with the one below:

```
$route[ 'default_controller' ]  = 'main';
$route[ '404_override' ]        = 'error404';

require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get( 'blog_slugs' );
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[ $row->slug ] = 'pages/slug_on_the_fly/$1;
}
```

All you would have to do then is to create a record when you create a blog entry and you're done:

```
INSERT INTO `blog_slugs` (`slug`) VALUES ('name-of-the-article');
```

Comment: Thanks, interresting concept. But what when I have e.g. 10 000 articles. It would be slow or not? In my case it is not a big deal. I have max. 50 pages/articles. But I am just curious ;)

Comment: you could cache the database query output. I have used an extended version of this that handles all my routes, with a cached file to read from the speed is fine (for me anyway). I use https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-cache

Answer (score 3):

Use the [404 override reserved route](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) controller/method. If a valid controller/route doesn't exist, this method will be called. Works great as a catch-all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you.

```
$route['controllerName/([^/]+)/([^/]+)'] = "index/author/$1/$2";
```

Answer (score 1):

This can help you

`$route['controllerName/(:any)] = "controllename/method/slug";`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have 3 controllers other than pages controller say controller1, controller2 and controller3 then,

```
$route['^(?!controller1|controller2|controller3).*'] = 'pages/slug_on_the_fly/$1';;
```